# Deleting questions without any options to answer or remediate objections unwelcoming

Tags: discussion

This is not specific to this site but here I've got an example so writing here.

The example is https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/70037/24923

My answer was removed, there is no way to object or correct based on feedback. It is deleted, then I can vote to undelete but that is flawed mechanism IMO as it goes to some shady queue where it may not receive much if at all attention.

I think that downvoting is a better indicator if answer is bad. Deleting should be done IMO when things are completely off like spam or other inappropriate content.

Comment: "there is no way to object or correct based on feedback" - yes there is. You can object by posting on Meta, like you've done here, and assuming I understand what you mean by 'correct based on feedback', you can do that by editing the answer and voting to undelete. I understand why you believe the latter system to be flawed, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist entirely.

Comment: @F1Krazy, I'm raising an issue about site policies and mechanisms. This answer - whatever. Even I'm probably not going to hang-up much in this particular community. I raised because I tried to be helpful to network. I participate more on other sites. But it seems at some point rules become more important than usefulness.

Answer (score 5):

I deleted that answer because it doesn't answer the question. [The question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/70023) asks about the following:

> One comment goes as far as jokingly saying "So technically, Switzerland also accidentally invaded France with a one-man army" when a soldier going home fell asleep in a train and ended up in France.

Your answer provided an example of US troops mistaking a Bulgarian factory for an airbase which they thought was part of their training exercise.

That's a different situation (the troops were already in Bulgaria) and you didn't address if it's considered an invasion.

You've since added the following line to [your answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/70037):

> So showing up where they shouldn't be, even conducting hostile activities didn't result in a conflict.

I don't think that makes it an answer to the question. You're still using that one anecdote and you don't address whether it can be considered an invasion or what would have made it an invasion. The situation in the question also didn't lead to a US-Swiss conflict so you're basically adding another example to the question.

Suppose you want to know what makes it an invasion when foreign troops show up in uniform. Does your answer provide any clarity on that? I (still) think the answer is *no*, meaning it doesn't answer the question. And yes, [non-answers may be deleted by the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292391).

I'm not saying that your example is unusable in addressing the question. If you can elaborate based on your example what consideration are relevant why it didn't constitute an invasion then that might extend to the different example in the question.

Comment: Question was `Even if by accident, is the act of military men showing up in a foreign country in full uniform considered an invasion?` and my answer shows that even hostile activity can be ignored. Question was not "when troops are considered and invasion" or at least it is an auxiliary question. If you believe that deleting my answer makes the site better and more useful, so be it. My opinion is still that it is an interesting and useful information for the question. And I don't feel welcome. Regards.